# Styles code appearing when page rendered as pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, renderas

I have a visualforce page which i am rendering as a pdf.

```
<apex:pages>
        <style>
          .cke_contents {
          height: 100px !important;
             }
        </style>
</apex:pages>
```

problem here is when I render the page as pdf , then pdf has below code visible on top of the page

```
.cke_contents {
          height: 100px !important;
             }
```

How can I hide this style code in PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `<apex:page>` attribute `applyBodyTag="false"`.